# Is there such a thing as an ordered pair in request parameters / query string? in GET request

Tags: http, url, httprequest, query-string

I'm writing an endpoint where it logically makes sense to think of request parameters as coupled ordered pairs
(eg `breed=labrador&name=fido`, `breed=dalmnation&name=mike` etc)

Is there anything I can do to enforce this pairing from the request
(eg having a dog object such that `dog1{breed=labrador&name=fido}&dog2{breed=dalmnation&name=mike}` or am I to just read the parameters in order and know that given a query know that the order matters and I must trust the ordering of the parameters would follow breed,name breed,name etc?

For context my endpoint would accept [1,15] dogs in a GET request and am using Django if that makes a difference.

I'm sorry if this has been asked before or is covered elsewhere, I'm struggling to find the right words to use to find a solution on Google.

Comment: Is this request a `GET` or `POST`?

Comment: GET, I will edit my post, thank you @Tsangares

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a `GET` request you could possibly put a json string inside one of the of the url encoded variables. Like this example with python request library:

```
import requests,json
dogs = [
 { "breed": "labrador", "name": "fido"},
 { "breed": "dalmnation", "name": "mike"}
]   
payload = { "json": json.dumps(dogs) }
requests.get("http://endpoint", params = payload);
```

Then on the receiving end:

```
def my(request):
  myDogs = json.loads(request.GET.get('json'))
```